# Selling a put option and getting assigned

Tags: options-assignment, put-options, td-ameritrade

I am using TD Ameritrade platform. Suppose I write a cash secured short put and the option expires in-the-money. The owner of the option then decides to exercise his right to sell.

I am okay with getting assigned since I wanted to get the stock at lower price anyway. In case the put option is OTM, I then get to keep the premium fee.

1. Will TDA charge me any fees for getting assigned? If yes, how much?
2. Does seller of Put option need to do anything upon expiry when the Put option expires ITM?
3. Will my money get deducted automatically and the underlying stock transferred into my account automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sell an option, you get to keep the premium no matter what when it expires.  This may or may not be a profit because if assigned, your purchase (or sale) price at the strike price could be worse than the market price of the underlying.

Per this [Ameritrade](https://www.tdameritrade.com/pricing.page)  link, their fee for assignment or exercise is $0.00.  You do not have to do anything at expiration.  The OCC and you broker will handle everything automatically.  The amount of the strike price will be deducted from your account and you will receive the shares.

Comment: If OP plans for this to occur frequently, not all brokers charge this fee. When I buy say, a $40 call, and sell the $50, if the stock is above the $50 upper strike at expiration, I wake up Monday with $1000 cash (less the tiny exchange fee). The buy and sell itself are the same $0 commission as other trades.

Comment: $19.99 for assignment/exercise isn't terrible if it's a flat fee and you're buying/selling in size.  But ZERO commission for assignment or exercise is much more preferable and as you said, it will add up if you do this frequently.